# Error deploying MVC3 - Cassette application on IIS8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, web-config, cassette

Works fine on the local machine, but when deployed this error message pops up:

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       BeginRequest
Handler    Not yet determined
Error Code     0x80070021
Config Error       This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\foo\web.config
Requested URL      http://foo.net:80/
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\foo
Logon Method       Not yet determined
Logon User     Not yet determined

Config Source:
   71:     </modules>
   72:     <handlers> <--- This part is highlighted on the error page.
   73:       <add name="CassetteHttpHandler" path="cassette.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" allowPathInfo="true" type="Cassette.Aspnet.CassetteHttpHandler, Cassette.Aspnet" />

More Information:
This error occurs when there is a problem reading the configuration file for the Web server or Web application. In some cases, the event logs may contain more information about what caused this error.
```

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this error was by going into the IIS Management window and selecting `Feature Delegation` and setting Read/Write to Handler Mappings and Modules.

Everything is working fine now.